# Android: Best way to keep static content in application

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to build an android application which has static content. I dont know where should I keep my static content. Shall I keep it in my xml file or use sqlite db. Or shall I keep my data in xml file and create the table when the application loads . Data wont change much over the period of time and only fetch operation has to be performed on the data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by static content? Are you talking about images/audio/video/text/binary files or just structured data?

Comment: creata a constant file in java and store it

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data which you want to store..If it is some small key value king of data use 
SharedPreferences otherwise you can use sqlite database if you relational data..Files are generally used to store non-relational data.

Refer http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html. to learn how to implement each of these techniques.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I'd opt for an XML file structure. The data handling code will be comparable but updates from the host database will be infinitely more efficient. Good luck with your project.